# Get geometry from OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo JSON

Tags: openlayers-2, geometry

I need to store the geometry of a certain feature with `OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo` and I'm using these parameters to get it in JSON format

```
output:'features',
infoFormat:'application/json',
format: new OpenLayers.Format.JSON,
```

After I store the geometry from the JSON, I'm writing a WKT string with it to get something like.

```
"MULTIPOLYGON(((-8.098636886812224 39.016921320632704, -8.098572979051546 39.016543430309326,)))"
```

The problem is that I don't know why but the JSON geometry object is coming with a comma  between the LAT and LONG  like so:

```
 "MULTIPOLYGON(((-8.098636886812224,39.016921320632704, -8.098572979051546, 39.016543430309326)))"
```

What's the best way to get a correct WKT string from the event.features JSON Object or in alternative how to replace every other comma  with a blank space using a regular expression in JavaScript?

Replacing the first and keeping the second?

Comment: please show the part of your code where you extract the json and convert it to wkt

Comment: I'm parsing the JSON by hand, but that's not the reason because the extra comma it's coming from the geoserver service as can be seen in the firebug log:

coordinates
 
 [[[[-8.113877153034096, 39.036574263049], [-8.113556220559316, 39.036444679026516], [-8.11329043426666, 39.036539575289424], 222 mais...]], [[[-8.121326178286509, 39.041446883512], [-8.121333757831637, 39.04101505567548], [-8.121333839614199, 39.04052233506628], 36 mais...]], [[[-8.073223234575162, 39.037794530137205], [-8.073426669662188, 39.03759719117027], [-8.073402069541089, 39.03800881124144], 34 mais...]], 16 mais...]

Comment: i would like to try this service, is it possible to access it over internet?

Comment: It's  still being developed in localhost. Nevertheless it's something that can easily be seen in the layer preview area of geoserver. Choosing for example GeoJSON in topp:states.  The same thing doesn't happen if one chooses GML. I guess i have to change things and try to parse it from GML.

I have the idea i'm over complicating things. Isn't there a easy way of getting the geometry from "event.features" of OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo?

Comment: why dont you make geoserver serving geojson or wkt instead of wms if what you need is the geometry?

Comment: I need the geometry and but i also need all the other properties. I preparing to create an edition mode where the selected feature and all it's attributes can be edited by WFS-Transaction.

Comment: i would like to do something similar, still im very new to openLayers, looking to your code, the Control .WMSGetFeatureInfo is part of the OL.JS, but which version?. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So after I got everything to work I want to share the code. I didn't need the WKT after all, I managed to save the geometry with GeoJSON only.

The result is this and with every property of the clicked features saved in a array so I can edit them later.

[image]

```
function settingInfoPopUp(){

    // POPUP de Info
    infoControl = new OpenLayers.Control.WMSGetFeatureInfo({
        url: 'http://localhost:9090/geoserver/mittic2/wms',
        title: 'Identify features by clicking',
        queryVisible: true,
        maxFeatures: 50,
        output:'features',
        infoFormat:'application/json',
        format: new OpenLayers.Format.JSON,

        eventListeners: {
            getfeatureinfo: function(event) {   

                if(popup != null){
                    map.removePopup(popup);
                    popup.destroy();
                    popup = null;
                }

                vectors.destroyFeatures();
                selectedFeaturesParse(event.features);

                if(selectedFeatures.length > 0){                                    
                    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud(
                        "featurePopup",
                        map.getLonLatFromPixel(event.xy),                       
                        null,
                        buildInfoControlTextAndVectors(),
                        null,
                        true
                    );
                    map.addPopup(popup);
                }
            }
        }
    });

    map.addControl(infoControl); 
    infoControl.activate();
}

function selectedFeaturesParse(jsonObject) {
    selectedFeatures = [];      
    for (var i=0 ; i < jsonObject.features.length; i++ ){
        selectedFeatures.push({
            objectid:jsonObject.features[i].properties.objectid, 
            conc_geoid: jsonObject.features[i].properties.conc_geoid,
            dicofre: jsonObject.features[i].properties.dicofre,
            lcover_typ: jsonObject.features[i].properties.lcover_typ,
            land_cultu: jsonObject.features[i].properties.land_cultu,
            area_efect: jsonObject.features[i].properties.area_efect,
            production: jsonObject.features[i].properties.production,
            energy_pot: jsonObject.features[i].properties.energy_pot,       
            geom: jsonObject.features[i].geometry           
        });
    }       
}

function buildInfoControlTextAndVectors(){
    var record; 
    var geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                'internalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:3857"),
                'externalProjection': new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
            });

    var feature;    
    var info = "<div class=\"info\">";

    for (var i=0 ; i < selectedFeatures.length; i++ ){
        record = selectedFeatures[i];

        // Aproveita o mesmo ciclo  que itera as formas selecionadas para desenhar também os vectores
        //**********************************************************
        feature = geojson_format.read(record.geom);
        vectors.addFeatures(feature);
        //**********************************************************

        info += "<div class=\"inner\"><table>"
        info += "<tr><td><b>ID: </b><td>" + record.objectid + "</td></tr>";
        info += "<tr><td><b>Concelho: </b><td>" + record.conc_geoid + "</td></tr>";
        info += "<tr><td><b>Freguesia: </b><td>" + record.dicofre + "</td></tr>";
        info += "<tr><td><b>Tipo de Coberto: </b><td>" + record.lcover_typ + "</td></tr>";
        info += "<tr><td><b>Ocupa&#231;&#227;o de Solo: </b><td>" + record.land_cultu + "</td></tr>";
        info += "<tr><td><b>&#193;rea Efectiva: </b><td>" + record.area_efect + " [ha]</td></tr>";
        info += "<tr><td><b>Produ&#231;&#227;o: </b><td>" + record.production + " [ton/ano]</td></tr>";
        info += "<tr><td><b>Potencial Energ&#233;tico: </b><td>" + record.energy_pot + " [MWh/ano]</td></tr></table></div>";

        if (i!= (selectedFeatures.length-1)){
            info += "<br />";
        }
    }

    info += "</div>"
    vectors.redraw();
    return info;
}
```